# Check for active connection in NHibernate

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I have a system with a few different databases, and I would like to check if a certain database is down, and if so display a message to the user.

Is it possible in NHibernate to check if there is an active connection to the database, without having to request data and then catch the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query the `state` column of [`sys.databases`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx)

ONLINE = OK, anything else = not available

```
SELECT state FROM master.sys.databases WHERE [name] = 'MyDB'
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM master.sys.databases WHERE [name] = 'MyDB' AND state = 'ONLINE'
```

Comment: Okay so I need to create that query, NHibernate doesn't have anything buildt in?

Comment: Not that I know of... you're asking for something that is SQL Server and DB specific rather that mapping an ORM

Comment: Can't you just query the state of ISession.Connection?

Comment: @Berryl: this won't tell you if a particular DB is available

Comment: I am sorry if I was unclear, but I just needed to check if the session was available without having to catch an exception.

Comment: @Dofs, @Berryl: ah OK. I worked on the "...certain database is down..." bit